# How to Handle Unable to Open the File in Android using External Application

Tags: java, android, java-io

```
    File file = new File(s);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    try {
         startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        file.delete();
        downloadFile(file);
    }
```

I am trying to Open the PDF using External Application in Android, if the File is fully downloaded it will open and show the PDF File.
If the File is empty or corrupted i want to delete the file and re Download it.

But i am not able to handle

> the Exception "The Document can't be Opened".

Comment: Where do you see that exception exactly? Show the stack trace.

Comment: `(s)`. You think the value of `s` is irrelevanf?

Comment: Where is your pdf file location? Because it depends for 3rd party app action to view.

Answer (score 0):

> But i am not able to handle
>   the Exception "The Document can't be Opened".

It's most likely because it is either outside the code snippet you shown, with `downloadFile()` being the possible code. If it is so, you need to have `try/catch` there (or at least around `downloadFile()` method invocation). Being in `catch()` will NOT make you automagically catch any subsequent exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen either your pdf file is not well formated so it is not able to open Or there is no application available which support to open pdf.

Let's check with this one for checking either file exists or not and if file exists then check for all applications which are having ACTION_VIEW intent filter.

```
try {
            File file = new File(s);
            if (file.exists()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                downloadFile(file);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            file.delete();
            downloadFile(file);
        }
```